# Laravel download from cloud storage throws file not found error

Tags: amazon-s3, download, laravel-6

I have a file stored in an s3 bucket. I can upload fine but when I try to download using the code below I get file not found exception thrown e.g.

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileNotFoundException
The file "https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mybucket/puppy.jpg" does not exist
```

When I navigate to the same url in a browser, the file downloads fine.

This is my code:

```
  return response()->download(Storage::disk('s3')->url($file->path), $file->name);
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work unless anyone know a more efficient technique:

```
 return response()->streamDownload(function () use ($file) {
        echo file_get_contents(Storage::disk('s3')->url($file->path));
    } , $file->name);
```